# Why does an (donor) ionized impurity in a P-N junction doesn't give rise to a hole in the depletion region?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When a donor impurity is depleted of its carrier why doesnt it turns into a hole rather than a stationary positive charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out into a vacancy in the orbital of the impurity but not in the valence band of the crystal.